# Чтобы создавать сайты с нуля необходимо знание python + django или ещё html + css?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я выучила на базовом уровне python и сейчас начинаю изучать фреймворк django.
Чтобы создавать сайты, нужно python + django или ещё нужно выучить HTML и CSS?

Comment: Да, нужно выучить `HTML` и `CSS`. Желательно ещё `JavaScript`. Но в целом всё зависит от того, что Вы имеете в виду под _"создавать сайты"_.

Comment: Если сайт от и до делать будете сами - то HTML, и CSS, и JS. Если только бэкэнд - хватит Python и Django + немного HTML.